# Difference between ko.validation.configure vs ko.validation.init

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Both are used to apply the knockout validation configurations on viewmodel. What is the different between these two statements?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like configure is there for backwards compatibility, and just calls init.

From the validation source (https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/Src/api.js#L120):

```
        // backwards compatability
        configure: function (options) { ko.validation.init(options); },
```

Comment: If your ko.validation is configured already & you want it to re-configure, then the best option is to use is ko.validation.init(options, true); - where true is to force to set the new configuration